# Is it Safe to open a liveserver on localhost:8080 for my website on public wifi?

Tags: security, localhost

Like mentioned in the title I want to work on my website in a Starbucks with Public wifi is there any risk of running a live server on public wifi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 main risks:

1) Someone will be able to know what you are developing. So if that's your super secret project - you'd better not do that.

2) If your website has security issues - someone could upload a backdoor to your PC and steal your passwords or other valuable information. Also, if other users are supposed to use this website through public WiFi - data could be overheard by other users, so SSL is getting more important.

To enhance security you can:

- Add basic HTTP authentication to your website. Work with SSL even
  on local server.
- Add a firewall rule restricting access to this port from outside if that's possible.
- Choose a random high port (>10000), so that it's a little bit
  harder to spot during routine port scan on known service ports.
- Run a website inside VM to isolate it from your valuable data. You
  can forward port inside your VM.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. The project I am working on is running with Django and it is not a super secret project. Will look into adding basic HTTP authentication to the local server.